# Ideas on how to simplify or approximate this nasty sum

Tags: summation, approximation

I have a sum (let's call it $p$):

$$p:= \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=2}^l (i-1)\frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k-i+2)!}(n-i)!$$

where $l, n, k$ are fixed positive integers, and $k \leq n$.

I'd like to either simplify or approximate $p$, for the purpose of simplifying or approximating the sum

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \binom{n}{k-1}(k-1)!\binom{n}{k}k! p^k$$

where $p$ is that nasty first sum we had.

I don't really know any approximation or numerical techniques, so any advice on how to simplify or approximate the first or second sum in such a way that the second sum would tend to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Wolfram alpha seems to think it's not so bad: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(i-1)%2A1%2FFactorial%5Bn-k-i%2B2%5D%2AFactorial%5Bn-i%5D,%7Bi,2,l%7D%5D

Comment: That looks a little messy to me but I'll try to work with it...approximation would be easier if there's any known method :)

Comment: Updated: trying to work with long answer wolfram gives...still not sure how to simplify

Comment: More accurately: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2FFactorial%5Bn%5D+(Sum%5B(i-1)*Factorial%5Bn-k%5D%2FFactorial%5Bn-k-i%2B2%5D*Factorial%5Bn-i%5D,%7Bi,2,l%7D%5D))